# How can I combine default component style with extra styles in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have page title component with some basic default styling:

```jsx
const PageTitle = (props) => {
    return (
        <Text style={styles.pageTitleDefault}>{props.Title}</Text>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    pageTitleDefault: {
        fontSize: 48,
        fontWeight: '600',
    },
});
```

Now, I am trying to make some extra styling in the place where I use the title:

```jsx
<PageTitle style={{marginTop: 100, color: 'red'}} Title="Nothing else matters" />
```

This of course does not work, the title has no margin and it is not red...

But then I got an idea and adjusted component render to code below:

```jsx
const PageTitle = (props) => {
    return (
        <Text style={[styles.pageTitleDefault, props.style]}>{props.Title}</Text>
    )
}
```

Everything works just fine, there is a margin and text becomes red.

Is this a good approach?

What is the recommended approach if I need to style some component
but still be able to do some tweaks (add/override styling) in place of use?

Comment: of course, you can use this way or use spread operator {{...styles.pageTitleDefault, ...props.style}}

Comment: @RagulCs thank you. I can see that works both ways. What now puzzles and looks weird to me is how the style values are used - they work even when I pass in array of arrays - `[[...], [...]]` e.g. `[styles.pageTitleDefault, props.style]`. Is there any official docs/specs on this?